# SQL Server 2008 : update a column based on loop on another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables:

```
create table  tblA (Pid int, Ltype varchar(2), upcoming_Ltype varchar(2))
insert into tblA (pid, ltype)
values
(123, 'A1'),
(123, 'C2'),
(567, 'B1'),
(457, 'A1')

create table tblB (Pid int, Ltype varchar(2), isactive bit)
insert into tblB (Pid, Ltype, isactive)
values
(123,'A1',1),
(123,'C2',1),
(123,'B1',1),
(123,'E2',1),

(567,'A1',1),
(567,'C2',1),
(567,'B1',1),
(567,'E2',1),

(457,'A1',1),
(457,'C2',0),
(457,'B1',1),
(457,'E2',1)
```

Here, note that in tblB, Ltype is always A1, C2, B1 and E2 in order for every Pid. Now, I want to populate upcoming_Ltype from tblA based on the next isactive = 1 Ltype from tblB

Expected result:

tblA:

```
(123, 'A1',C2), 
(123, 'C2',B1),
(567, 'B1',E2),
(457, 'A1',B1)   <-- skipping C2
```

Here's my effort(not working):

```
UPDATE tblA
SET upcoming_Ltype =
(
  SELECT Ltype
  FROM tblB
  WHERE tblA.Pid = tblB.Pid 
  AND tblB.isActive = 1
  AND tblB.Ltype > tblA.Ltype 
)
```

Comment: A1, C2, B1, E2 is order. We can assign them numbers, 1,2,3 and 4 respectively in temp table.

Answer (score -1):

Is that Bhupinder Singh from Pune?

If you create a select query to calculate the values then you can join to it in an update

```
use tempdb
CREATE Table #order_lkp
(Ltype varchar(2) not null UNIQUE, sortorder int identity)

INSERT #order_lkp VALUES('A1'), ('C2'), ('B1'), ('E2')

create table  tblA (Pid int, Ltype varchar(2), upcoming_Ltype varchar(2))
insert into tblA (pid, ltype)
values
(123, 'A1'),
(123, 'C2'),
(567, 'B1'),
(457, 'A1')

create table tblB (Pid int, Ltype varchar(2), isactive bit)
insert into tblB (Pid, Ltype, isactive)
values
(123,'A1',1),
(123,'C2',1),
(123,'B1',1),
(123,'E2',1),

(567,'A1',1),
(567,'C2',1),
(567,'B1',1),
(567,'E2',1),

(457,'A1',1),
(457,'C2',0),
(457,'B1',1),
(457,'E2',1)
GO
WITH UPCOMING_LKP AS
(
SELECT find_upcoming_sortorder.Pid, find_upcoming_sortorder.Ltype,
o.Ltype AS upcoming_Ltype 
 FROM 
(
SELECT 
ta.Pid, 
ta.Ltype, 
ta.sortorder
,MIN(tb.sortorder )
AS upcoming_sortorder
FROM 
(SELECT tblA.Ltype,tblA.Pid,sortorder FROM tblA JOIN  #order_lkp ON tblA.Ltype =  #order_lkp.Ltype) ta
LEFT JOIN  
(SELECT tblB.Ltype,tblB.Pid,sortorder FROM tblB JOIN  #order_lkp ON tblB.Ltype =  #order_lkp.Ltype WHERE tblB.isactive <> 0 ) tb
ON 
ta.Pid= tb.Pid  
AND tb.sortorder > ta.sortorder 
GROUP BY ta.Pid, ta.Ltype 
,ta.sortorder
) find_upcoming_sortorder
JOIN #order_lkp o ON o.sortorder = find_upcoming_sortorder.upcoming_sortorder
)


UPDATE a 
SET a.upcoming_Ltype = lkp.upcoming_Ltype
FROM tblA  a
JOIN UPCOMING_LKP lkp ON a.Pid = lkp.Pid AND a.Ltype = lkp.Ltype


GO
DROP table  tblA ;
GO
DROP table  tblB;
GO
DROP Table #order_lkp
```